# JavaScript/ajax site reaload

Tags: javascript, php

sorry for my bad english google help me :-)
with my script, if i enter something in the database, it is displayed without a page reload. Now I wanted to ask if this is so good or can it be improved? I know javascript/Ajax and what's not out there. I just want that if something is written into the db with a form, it's displayed immediately without page reload, like a kind of shoutbox.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Ausgabe</title>
  </head>
  <body onload = "table();">
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function table(){
        const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onload = function(){
          document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
        xhttp.open("GET", "system.php");
        xhttp.send();
      }

      setInterval(function(){
        table();
      }, 1);
    </script>
    <div id="table">

    </div>
  </body>
</html>

<?php
 $host_name = '';
 $database = '';
 $user_name = '';
 $password = '';

 $link = new mysqli($host_name, $user_name, $password, $database);

 if ($link->connect_error) {
   die('<p>Verbindung zum MySQL Server fehlgeschlagen: '. $link->connect_error .'</p>');
 } 
$rows = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM tb_data");
?>
<table border = 1 cellpadding = 10>
  <tr>
    <td>#</td>
    <td>Name</td>
  </tr>
  <?php $i = 1; ?>
  <?php foreach($rows as $row) : ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $i++; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></td>
    </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Well, an interval of `1` might be a bit overkill. Remember, that's in milliseconds, so with `1` it will call `table()` 1000 times per second.

Comment: This might belong on https://codereview.stackexchange.com - but check their rules before moving it there.

Comment: what can i improve? what can i change in the code to improve it? is there another better technique?